# How to implement single choose and range in an app

Tags: flutter, dart

The title might be a bit confusing, so here's what I want to implement:
[image: with switch off:]
[image: with switch on:]

I tried to find a package to make things easier but I couldn't find any, so if you know any packages or flutter widgets that can help my situation, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: how have you done the single tag implementation? thats depends and have multiple ways to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this with a row of buttons, then put an integer variable to track which one is currently selected?

```
int _currentlySelected = 0;
final List<String> _buttonTexts = ["Any", "Studio", "So on..."];
```

And render the buttons dynamically using List.generate().

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: List.generate(
        _buttonTexts.length,
        (i) => OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _currentlySelected = i;
                }),
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: _currentlySelected == i ? const Color(0xff131313) : const Color(0xffffffff),
              foregroundColor: _currentlySelected == i ? const Color(0xffffffff) : const Color(0xff131313),
            ),
    child: Text(_buttonTexts[i]))));
```